# RacSignal disposed automatically

Tags: ios, error-handling, merge, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

I have merged some racsignals into a single Racsignal. And subscribed the merged signal. Now if any of the signals that i have merged sends error event all the merged signals are disposed. I want all the signals to continue there executing if any signal has failed.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two options:

1. Apply `catchTo:[RACSignal empty]` to each signal to squelch any signal that errors.
2. Apply `-materialize` to each signal which changes all subscriber events into concrete instances of `RACEvent`.

Using option #1 drops the error objects and prevents the other merged signals from being disposed, but leaves the subscriber uninformed about all errors.

Using option #2 means your subscriber has to unwrap the `RACEvent` and then conditionally perform the value or error handling logic, inside the `next` block.